# Registering API in apps

Tags: django, json, rest, django-rest-framework, urlconf

With django-rest-framework I'm using the `DefaultRouter`

I want to provide APIs to several apps, so my question is can I do this in a django manner and put my router registrations in each app URLconf and have them appear either as one aggregate api or ideally in a namespaced way.

In other words if `app1` contains `modelA` and `modelB`, while `app2` contains `modelC`:

1. can I declare 2 routers that appear at `mysite/app1/api` and `mysite/app2/api`, or
2. can I have a single api at `mysite/api` which lists all three models yet register the individual models in their own app's `urls.py`

Something like

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)
router.register(include('app1.apis')
router.register(include('app2.apis')
```

Alternatively is there a simple way in which my router variable can be made available in each app's URLconf so that they can call `router.register`? I'm not sure if

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^snippets/', include('snippets.urls', namespace="snippets"))
...
url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
```

actually cause the code in `app1/urls.py` to be executed at that point so that it could call `router.register` somehow, so that the final url call includes all the app registrations as well as the project one.

**UPDATE**

Using a variation on Nicolas Cortot's `option 2` I get my specific resource `API` to work, but it is not listed as an available resource in the `root API` at `myserver\api\`

I assume that somehow `DefaultRouter` creates it's own page definition and `router.register` adds entries to it. My current setup (and I think Nicholas's option 1 as well) create two separate routers, and only one can get displayed as the server root, with the setup below, `myserver\api\` lists `users` but not snippets.

Here's my current setup:

**project urls.py:**

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api/', include('snippets.apiurls')),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
)
```

**project/snippets/apiurls.py:**

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'snippets', views.SnippetViewSet)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
)
```

If I reverse the order of the entries in the project `urls.py` as:

```
    url(r'^api/', include('snippets.apiurls')),
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
```

then I get `snippets` listed but not `users`

I guess Django is serving the first matching route.

Unless someone can tell me otherwise I seem to need a single router variable to be passed around and added to somehow.

Answer (score 16):

To get all apps in the same API root, you need to register all your apps with the same DefaultRouter.

One way to achieve this is to make a custom router, which intercepts the register call and propagates it to a shared router. You then use this shared router to get the api urls.

```
class SharedAPIRootRouter(SimpleRouter):
    shared_router = DefaultRouter()

    def register(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.shared_router.register(*args, **kwargs)
        super().register(*args, **kwargs)
        # if not py3: super(SharedAPIRootRouter, self).register(*args,**kwargs)
```

Then in each app:

```
# in app1/urls.py 
router = SharedAPIRootRouter()
router.register(r'app1', App1ModelViewSet)

# in app2/urls.py
router = SharedAPIRootRouter()
router.register(r'app2', App2ModelViewSet)
```

In your main urls.py, you must ensure you import the app urls so that registration occurs before we ask for shared_router.urls

```
import app1.urls
import app2.urls

def api_urls():
    return SharedAPIRootRouter.shared_router.urls

urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^api/', include(api_urls())),   
)
```

if you do not want to import the urls explicitly, you can do it by convention:

```
def api_urls():
    from importlib import import_module
    for app in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
        try:
            import_module(app + '.urls')
        except (ImportError, AttributeError):
            pass
    return SharedAPIRootRouter.shared_router.urls
```

Comment: Where should I put class SharedAPIRootRouter ? (in what file?)

Comment: @yestema in whatever file you want really. And then in each app you import from that file.

Answer (score 7):

This is possible by passing around a single router instance as follows.

Create a file called `router.py` or similar in your `main` project folder:

```
from rest_framework import routers
common_router = routers.DefaultRouter()
```

In each app's `urls.py` put:

```
from main.router import common_router as router
router.register(r'myapp-model-name', MyAppViewSet)
```

In your `main` `urls.py` put:

```
import my_app1.urls  # to register urls with router
import my_app2.urls  # to register urls with router
...
# finally import router that includes all routes
from main.router import common_router

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^api/', include(common_router.urls)),
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 5):

Both options are possible. You can either expose the `router` or the `urls` in each app, and merge those into your global `urls`. I usually prefer using `urls` (option 2) because it gives more flexibility in each app: you can define extra non-api URLs as needed.

### Option 1

In your global **urls.py**:

```
from app1.api.routers import router1
from app2.api.routers import router2

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^snippets/', include('snippets.urls', namespace="snippets"))
    ...
    url(r'^app1/api/', include(router1.urls)),
    url(r'^app2/api/', include(router2.urls)),
)
```

You can as easily use the same endpoint for both routers (as long as you're careful not to use conflicting routes):

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^snippets/', include('snippets.urls', namespace="snippets"))
    ...
    url(r'^api/', include(router1.urls)),
    url(r'^api/', include(router2.urls)),
)
```

### Option 2

In **appN/api/urls.py**:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)
router.register(include('app1.apis')

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^misc/', some_other_view),
)
```

In your global **urls.py**:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^snippets/', include('snippets.urls', namespace="snippets"))
    ...
    url(r'^api/', include('app1.api.urls')),
    url(r'^api/', include('app2.api.urls')),
)
```

Note that the `urls` modules do not need to be the same as the `urls` for standard views.

Comment: I tried option 2 as it seems a lot neater. A slight variation on it is that I created `appN/apiurls.py` rather than a subdirectory. The specific urls work and I can get a JSON response. However they don't get listed in the API root. I'll post the code as an update to my question in case I've messed it up somehow.

Comment: Option 1 doesn't work. You will have only urls from app1!

Answer (score 0):

As a more advanced variant on [@Grischa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37656066/5081021), I like to extend his approach:

In the main's `routers.py`:

```
from rest_framework import routers

api_v1_router = routers.SimpleRouter()
```

In the main's `urls.py`:

```
from django.urls import include, path

import app1.urls
from .routers import api_v1_router

# Register app urls
app1.urls.register(api_v1_router)
app2.urls.register(api_v1_router)
...

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('v1/', include((api_v1_router.urls, 'v1'))),
    ...
]
```

In each app's `urls.py`:

```
from main.routers import api_v1_router
from .apis import MyAppViewSet1, MyAppViewSet2


def register(router):
    router.register(r'myapp-model-name1', MyAppViewSet1)
    router.register(r'myapp-model-name2', MyAppViewSet2)
```

Two advantages of this approach:

1. You can control the registration of the apps in the main `urls.py`
2. The flexibility of `register(router)` allows you to register to different routers, for example when using both v1 and v2 for versioning.